# Exception fault: ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable ::_fileSystemType is not defined. ->? iOS AIR app crashes hard

Tags: ios, air, adobe

I'm stuck with debugging our Adobe AIR Application since it does crash very hard. After days of tracking down at least one point where the app crashes on AIR 3.5, 3.7 and AIR 3.8 beta (you see - I tried...).

**AIR 3.5 finally reports this trace output:**

```
ScrollerTouch.onTargetMouseDown()-F true // A
ScrollerTouch.onTargetMouseDown()-I // B
targetV [object ScrollPane] // C
CRASH! // D
Exception fault: ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable ::_fileSystemType is not defined.
          at global/trace()[int:49]
          at de.superclass.control::ScrollerTouch/onTargetMouseDown()[/path/to/.../ScrollerTouch.as:381]
          at de.superclass.control::ScrollerTouch/onTargetMouseDown()
```

**The ActionScript code snipped:**

```
trace("ScrollerTouch.onTargetMouseDown()-F", _scrollHorizontal ); // A

switch ( _scrollPolicyVertical )
{
    case ScrollPolicy.ON:
        trace("ScrollerTouch.onTargetMouseDown()-G");
        _scrollVertical = true;
        break;

    case ScrollPolicy.OFF:
        trace("ScrollerTouch.onTargetMouseDown()-H");
        _scrollVertical = false;
        break;

    case ScrollPolicy.AUTO:
        trace("ScrollerTouch.onTargetMouseDown()-I"); // B

    default:
        trace( "targetV", targetV ); // C
        try
        {
            trace( "targetV.height", targetV.height );
        }
        catch( e: Error )
        {
            trace( "CRASH!" ); // D
        }

        // line 381 throws the hard crash:
        _scrollVertical = Boolean( targetV.height < targetV.contentHeight );

        trace( "targetV.xxx" );
        trace( "targetV.contentHeight", targetV.contentHeight );
        return;
}
```

So accessing targetV.height on line 381 somehow crashes very hard (app quits) but I have no clue why. Actually, this code worked for a long time...

*Additional info:*

I changed the code again but the app keeps crashing. This is what XCode-Console says:

```
Jul  4 21:25:48 iRad-3 ReportCrash[1206] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process APP_NAME[1191]
Jul  4 21:25:48 iRad-3 backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jul  4 21:25:48 iRad-3 backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jul  4 21:25:48 iRad-3 backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jul  4 21:25:48 iRad-3 ReportCrash[1206] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary
Jul  4 21:25:48 iRad-3 com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:APP_NAME_SPACE[0x469][1191]) <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:APP_NAME_SPACE[0x469]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11
Jul  4 21:25:48 iRad-3 backboardd[26] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:APP_NAME_SPACE[0x469]' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11
Jul  4 21:25:48 iRad-3 ReportCrash[1206] <Notice>: Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/APP_NAME_2013-07-04-212547_iRa d-3.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0
Jul  4 21:25:55 iRad-3 kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[1207] Builtin profile: container (sandbox)
Jul  4 21:25:55 iRad-3 kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[1207] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/CDA04278-5D34-4609-BE71-D66FB16794C1 (sandbox)
Jul  4 21:25:56 iRad-3 kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[1208] Builtin profile: PasteBoard (sandbox)
Jul  4 21:25:56 iRad-3 backboardd[26] <Warning>: CoreAnimation: updates deferred for too long
Jul  4 21:25:56 iRad-3 backboardd[26] <Warning>: CoreAnimation: timed out fence 2685b
```

*And here's the Crash Log:*

```
Incident Identifier: 17615510-16A5-43B9-B8A5-2ED2C5A2EEBA
CrashReporter Key:   3f85661334bfff23c2d4128bc63674d30647c15b
Hardware Model:      iPad3,3
Process:         APP_NAME [1191]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/CDA04278-5D34-4609-BE71-D66FB16794C1/APP_NAM E.app/APP_NAME
Identifier:      APP_NAME
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-07-04 21:25:47.935 +0200
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.3 (10B329)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x4095e008
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   APP_NAME        0x008c71c8 0x1000 + 9200072
1   APP_NAME        0x005284ac 0x1000 + 5403820
2   APP_NAME        0x007b5edc 0x1000 + 8081116
3   APP_NAME        0x00002928 0x1000 + 6440
4   APP_NAME        0x0045f128 0x1000 + 4579624
5   APP_NAME        0x0045f5f8 0x1000 + 4580856
6   APP_NAME        0x0045eeb4 0x1000 + 4578996
7   APP_NAME        0x0045eab4 0x1000 + 4577972
8   APP_NAME        0x003d98d8 0x1000 + 4032728
9   APP_NAME        0x003c59c0 0x1000 + 3951040
10  APP_NAME        0x00443d24 0x1000 + 4468004
11  APP_NAME        0x009d5448 0x1000 + 10306632
12  APP_NAME        0x009d509c 0x1000 + 10305692
13  APP_NAME        0x009d4ad0 0x1000 + 10304208
14  APP_NAME        0x009d6618 0x1000 + 10311192
15  APP_NAME        0x00cf4d40 0x1000 + 13581632
16  APP_NAME        0x00a5f418 0x1000 + 10871832
17  APP_NAME        0x008d810c 0x1000 + 9269516
18  APP_NAME        0x009b45ac 0x1000 + 10171820
19  APP_NAME        0x009b5140 0x1000 + 10174784
20  UIKit                         0x347ff51e -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 314
21  UIKit                         0x347ec7fc -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 376
22  UIKit                         0x347ec116 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6150
23  GraphicsServices              0x364e05a0 _PurpleEventCallback + 588
24  GraphicsServices              0x364e01ce PurpleEventCallback + 30
25  CoreFoundation                0x329b9170 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
26  CoreFoundation                0x329b9112 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
27  CoreFoundation                0x329b7f94 __CFRunLoopRun + 1380
28  CoreFoundation                0x3292aeb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
29  CoreFoundation                0x3292ad44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
30  GraphicsServices              0x364df2e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
31  UIKit                         0x348402fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
32  APP_NAME        0x008f5c0c 0x1000 + 9391116
33  APP_NAME        0x00d2b0e0 0x1000 + 13803744

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x3ad76648 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib             0x3aca6974 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 792
2   libdispatch.dylib             0x3aca6654 _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 32

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x3ad75eb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x3ad76048 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                0x329b9040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124
3   CoreFoundation                0x329b7d9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878
4   CoreFoundation                0x3292aeb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                0x3292ad44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   WebCore                       0x3891a500 RunWebThread(void*) + 440
7   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3acdf30e _pthread_start + 306
8   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3acdf1d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x3ad75eb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x3ad76048 mach_msg + 36
2   APP_NAME        0x00480b04 0x1000 + 4717316
3   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3acdf30e _pthread_start + 306
4   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3acdf1d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x3ad8608c __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3acd7d2a _pthread_cond_wait + 642
2   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3ace1f14 pthread_cond_wait + 36
3   APP_NAME        0x00a33ad4 0x1000 + 10693332
4   APP_NAME        0x0097d9e0 0x1000 + 9947616
5   APP_NAME        0x00a33938 0x1000 + 10692920
6   APP_NAME        0x00a3398c 0x1000 + 10693004
7   APP_NAME        0x00a336b8 0x1000 + 10692280
8   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3acdf30e _pthread_start + 306
9   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3acdf1d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x3ad8608c __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3acd7d2a _pthread_cond_wait + 642
2   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3ace1f14 pthread_cond_wait + 36
3   APP_NAME        0x00a33ad4 0x1000 + 10693332
4   APP_NAME        0x0097d9e0 0x1000 + 9947616
5   APP_NAME        0x00a33938 0x1000 + 10692920
6   APP_NAME        0x00a3398c 0x1000 + 10693004
7   APP_NAME        0x00a336b8 0x1000 + 10692280
8   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3acdf30e _pthread_start + 306
9   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3acdf1d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x3ad866a4 __semwait_signal + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3ace43ce nanosleep + 138
2   APP_NAME        0x00a33724 0x1000 + 10692388
3   APP_NAME        0x00913638 0x1000 + 9512504
4   APP_NAME        0x009135d8 0x1000 + 9512408
5   APP_NAME        0x00a33938 0x1000 + 10692920
6   APP_NAME        0x00a3398c 0x1000 + 10693004
7   APP_NAME        0x00a336b8 0x1000 + 10692280
8   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3acdf30e _pthread_start + 306
9   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3acdf1d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x3ad8608c __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3acd7d2a _pthread_cond_wait + 642
2   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3acd7aa0 pthread_cond_timedwait + 40
3   APP_NAME        0x00a33b54 0x1000 + 10693460
4   APP_NAME        0x000a7254 0x1000 + 680532
5   APP_NAME        0x00a33938 0x1000 + 10692920
6   APP_NAME        0x00a3398c 0x1000 + 10693004
7   APP_NAME        0x00a336b8 0x1000 + 10692280
8   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3acdf30e _pthread_start + 306
9   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3acdf1d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x3ad866a4 __semwait_signal + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3ace43ce nanosleep + 138
2   APP_NAME        0x00a33724 0x1000 + 10692388
3   APP_NAME        0x008caff0 0x1000 + 9215984
4   APP_NAME        0x008cae08 0x1000 + 9215496
5   APP_NAME        0x00a33938 0x1000 + 10692920
6   APP_NAME        0x00a3398c 0x1000 + 10693004
7   APP_NAME        0x00a336b8 0x1000 + 10692280
8   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3acdf30e _pthread_start + 306
9   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3acdf1d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 9 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x3ad75eb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x3ad76048 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                0x329b9040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124
3   CoreFoundation                0x329b7d9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878
4   CoreFoundation                0x3292aeb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                0x3292ad44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   Foundation                    0x332773d0 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 304
7   Foundation                    0x332fae80 __NSThread__main__ + 968
8   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3acdf30e _pthread_start + 306
9   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3acdf1d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 10 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x3ad86594 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                0x329bd1f2 __CFSocketManager + 674
2   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3acdf30e _pthread_start + 306
3   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3acdf1d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x3ad86d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3acd4cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3acd4a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3acd48a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x3ad8608c __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3acd7d68 _pthread_cond_wait + 704
2   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3aceb080 pthread_cond_timedwait_relative_np + 12
3   APP_NAME        0x00a7e558 0x1000 + 10999128
4   APP_NAME        0x00a7e200 0x1000 + 10998272
5   APP_NAME        0x00a7e0f8 0x1000 + 10998008
6   APP_NAME        0x00a33938 0x1000 + 10692920
7   APP_NAME        0x00a3398c 0x1000 + 10693004
8   APP_NAME        0x00a336b8 0x1000 + 10692280
9   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3acdf30e _pthread_start + 306
10  libsystem_c.dylib             0x3acdf1d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x3ad86d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3acd4cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3acd4a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3acd48a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x4095e000    r1: 0x2fdfdf58      r2: 0x0052844c      r3: 0x2fdfdf1c
    r4: 0x00000221    r5: 0x084d8060      r6: 0x2fdfdf14      r7: 0x2fdfdf88
    r8: 0x2fdfdf20    r9: 0x000003fe     r10: 0x4095e000     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x000002fc    sp: 0x2fdfdf10      lr: 0x005284b0      pc: 0x008c71c8
  cpsr: 0x20000010

Binary image...
```

This immediately occurs when I touch and move a little on a specific display object which listens to Mouse-Events DOWN, MOVE to drag it's contents. I think it has something to do with the event system or so. But I'm absolutely blind I guess.

**So first question: Please, what is ::_fileSystemType ?**

**Who has a clue what the crash-log and XCode console output means?**

Comment: Maybe your file(s) are corrupted. Try creating a new flash-file or project and copy over the content and see if the problem still exists. I had some strange errors also, but when re-creating the files and copying over the content, it was gone. Not sure if its the case here, i assume you are running on Mac?

Comment: Hi and thanks! Yes, I use OS X. I thought about corrupt files as well, that's why I downloaded and reinstalled Flex and AIR SDKs, but it didn't do the trick. This is a really huge ActionScript project so I can't recreate every single .as file, there are several hundreds. I now have the App running again without using a special event-handling for touch control. I'll keep you informed. But I still wonder if somebody could explain a little more what the log and crash report actually means. :)

Comment: Maybe this is really related to file system rights? I don't know why, but now my code doesn't break anymore but I didn't change it massive. But I reinstalled my Flex and AIR SDKs, checked out the SVN data again and stuff like that. Maybe just a asset file was corrupt?